# Why I am getting " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"?

Tags: php

I have two pages in php the first contain a form which is:

```
<form method="post" action="addnames.php">
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br />

   <input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
```

this takes the data to other php page where I am using foreach to read the request in this way:

```
 foreach($_REQUEST['name'] as $name){ 
     //MY CODE
 }
```

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get `name` as an array then you need to change your form code:

```
<form method="post" action="addnames.php">
   <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" /><br />

   <input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
```

Now you can get all names in your `post` request.

Comment: Upvoting because I didn't know you could do that, and it's very cool.

Answer (score 1):

Because only one `name` is sent to the server, and it's a string then not an array. To send an array of names, change your input name to `name="name[]"` to identify it as an array

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
foreach($_REQUEST['name'] as $name){ 
 //MY CODE
}?>

<form method="post" action="addnames.php">
   <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name" /><br />

   <input type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
```